# Calculating distance between locations

Tags: php, coordinates, distance, haversine

I calculate distance between locations using havershine formula.

```
$distance = (((acos(sin(($fromLat * pi() / 180)) * sin(($toLat * pi( )/ 180)) + cos(($fromLat * pi() / 180)) * cos(($toLat * pi() / 180)) * cos((($fromLon - $toLon) * pi() / 180)))) * 180 / pi()) * 60 * 1.1515);
```

It works normally, but for some coordinate values it is giving `NAN`.

Values it gives `NAN` for are

```
fromLat : 22.303894
fromLon : 70.802162
toLat : 22.303894
toLon : 70.802162
```

Comment: Do you mean `toLon : 70.802162` rather than `toLat : 70.802162`?

Comment: If NaN then distance = 0.0

Comment: @MarkBaker Edited question. When distance is 0 then gives 0. For other set of values distance is 0 so it gives 0 there instead of `NAN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing the same coordinates. The `acos` function is being asked to calculate the arc cosine of 1, which fails. You will want to check if the coordinates are identical before passing it through the function. Also, if you're not getting a number, the result is probably no distance.